# SSAS: programmatically & permanently create calculated member

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to permanently create a calculated dimension member using a MDX ADOMD command from C# code.
The following MDX script creates the member but it's only available for the current session.

```
CREATE MEMBER [Cube].[Dimension].[Hierarchy].[My Member Name] as 
    Aggregate({
        [Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level].&[1], [Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level].&[2], ...
    })
```

How to permanently create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried it, but I found some AMO code that appears to do this, it's loading the current MDX calculation script from the cube, adding to it, then posting it back.

```
Dim objServer As Server
Dim objDatabase As Database
Dim strDataBaseID As String
Dim objCube As Cube
Dim objMdxScript As MdxScript
Dim objCommand As Command
Dim strCommand As String
objServer = New Server
objServer.Connect(“localhost”)
objDatabase = objServer.Databases(“Adventure Works DW 2008″)
strDataBaseID = objDatabase.ID
If objDatabase.Cubes.Count > 0 Then
objCube = objDatabase.Cubes(“Adventure Works”)
If objCube.MdxScripts.Count > 0 Then
objMdxScript = objCube.MdxScripts(“MdxScript”)
”objMdxScript = objCube.MdxScripts(0) 
Else
objCube.MdxScripts.Add(“MdxScript”, “MdxScript”)
objMdxScript = objCube.MdxScripts(“MdxScript”)
End If
objCommand = New Command
strCommand = “CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Multipy Measures By 20]“
strCommand = strCommand & ” AS [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] * 20, “
strCommand = strCommand & ” VISIBLE = 1 ; “
objCommand.Text = strCommand
objMdxScript.Commands.Add(objCommand)
objMdxScript.Update()
objCube.Update()
End If
objServer.Disconnect()
```

Found at http://www.win8s.com/sql-server/sql-server-analysis-services/2011/programically-changing-calculated-members.html

I use AMO elsewhere, but haven't used it like this, so do report back on results :)